# Visual Studio 2019 Docker - Manually created .net core 3.1 containers not opening in browser

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I have below 2 local linux docker containers running, which has .net core 3.1 web api in it and all properties looks similar below.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
07b119884a5a        servicetwo:dev      "tail -f /dev/null"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:32770->80/tcp   ServiceTwo_1
e54497742108        servicetwo:dev      "tail -f /dev/null"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp   ServiceTwo
```

Container ServiceTwo_1 has been created by Visual Studio on click the docker debug button in it. This is able to load in browser through http://localhost:32770/api/weatherforecast/weather.

But container "ServiceTwo" has been manually created using same command what Visual Studio used, like below.

```
docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\jaish\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "C:\Users\jaish\source\repos\ServiceTwo\ServiceTwo:/app" -v "C:\Users\jaish\source\repos\ServiceTwo:/src" -v "C:\Users\jaish\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -v "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -P --name ServiceTwo --entrypoint tail servicetwo:dev -f /dev/null
```

But this container not able to load in a browser using it's port i.e. http://localhost:32769/api/weatherforecast/weather

Did I missed any steps n the manual process?

Answer (score 1):

looks like your port mapping might be an issue

```
0.0.0.0:32770->80/tcp   ServiceTwo_1
0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp   ServiceTwo
```

Check what you get as a result after running these queries

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
b650456536c7        busybox:latest      top                 54 minutes ago      Up 54 minutes       0.0.0.0:1234->9876/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4321->7890/tcp   test
$ docker port test
7890/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:4321
9876/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:1234
$ docker port test 7890/tcp
0.0.0.0:4321
$ docker port test 7890/udp
2014/06/24 11:53:36 Error: No public port '7890/udp' published for test
$ docker port test 7890
0.0.0.0:4321
```

Reference : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/

Comment: The queries return as expected i.e.PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker port ServiceTwo_1
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32771
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker port ServiceTwo
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32769
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker port ServiceTwo_1 80/tcp
0.0.0.0:32771
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker port ServiceTwo 80/tcp
0.0.0.0:32769. But I noticed one more thing as Container created by Visual Studio i.e.ServiceTwo_1, not loading in browser till you start a docker debug session with VS. So is there any thing additional loading during VS docker debug ?session?